# Self imposed spening limit on a credit card account

Tags: credit-card, budget

I want to impose limit on my Amex account where I have 4 cards atm. That is let's say I want limit to be 5000 USD per month and when any card will spend 4000 USD than none of the cards should be allowed to spend 1001 USD that month. I called Amex and this is not possible, they don't allow self imposed limit on main card and only on "other users" card's and each limit is per card...

Is there a way to achieve this with other credit card in the US? Thanks!

Comment: How difficult is it to look at your balance(s) before you use the card? Seems like that would be better than getting transactions rejected and having to deal with the vendor. And why do you need 4 different cards?

Comment: It's a family account with 4 pepole.. I like peace of mind and automatic guard which limit brings, I guess I could check balance every time making major purchase, however that is some overhead I'm trying to avoid.. On the other hand it's a good habit to keep in touch with monthly spending.. Card being rejected is major pita when it happens when paying for Uber for example yeah...

Comment: Okay I misread that as four different accounts. I see the practicality more now.

Comment: That seems an awkward way to go about it. So you are paying in a restaurant and the card is declined because you have hit the limit. What would you do then ? It seems it's better to check your balance before incurring the expense, not when using the card when you already have incurred the expense.

Comment: @Hilmar I see that too, I'm thinking this will happen only last couple days in a month when everyone should be extra careful so we as a family fit into the monthly spending budget and if that will happen you will use emergency card to get out of that situation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since it sounds like you may not want a hard limit (e.g. transactions over the limit are declined), what about setting up an alert on the account?

Under **Account Services > Account Alerts**, you can choose to have them send you an email or text to let you know when you've passed a threshold that you specify.

[image]

Comment: In particular, if I'm reading the above screen correctly, at the beginning of every month/cycle, you could set the "_Get an alert when your Total Balance reaches_" value to $4,000 more than whatever the current balance is, if you carry a balance.

Comment: thanks Cody, this will do

Answer (score 1):

You probably want a pre-paid credit card to do what you are trying to accomplish and just top it up every month.

Even if your scheme to lower your limit works, you will probably get hit with fees for going over the limit. I know Amex in particular likes to claim they don't have a limit so that might make it even harder.